# Delete the image from field if publication is older than XX days

Tags: rules

I have Drupal 7, "Blog" content type, which has image field. Task: if the publication is older than 90 days, delete the image from field.

The idea was to use Views Bulk Operations for filtering (has a date between -90 / -91 days) and a Action set of Rules to remove images from the selected node field (run every day). At this stage, I could not understand how to change the value of the image field in action. Can anyone help?

Any other implementation ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Answer: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/1386746#comment-9738271

Comment: Just a thought but if the image was a referenced content type, you could use the scheduling module to unpublished the image content type...?

Comment: Thank you for participating, but the essence of the idea is to delete old pictures to clean the disk. The issue is resolved. VBO + Rules!